# Second thread runs only after the first thread completes instead of running in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Second thread runs only after the first thread completes instead of running in parallel.

```py
from threading import Thread
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,thread_no):
        self.thread_no = thread_no

    def fun(self):
        print(self.thread_no)

    def caller(self):
        while True:
            self.fun()
    def init(self):
        self.thread =Thread(target=self.caller)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    O1 = MyClass(1).init()
    O2 = MyClass(2).init()
```

**output**

```
1
1
1
...
```

basically it is waiting for the first thread to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to create instances first, then call `join()` later?

```py
from threading import Thread
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,thread_no):
        self.thread_no = thread_no
        self.start()

    def fun(self):
        print(self.thread_no)

    def caller(self):
        while True:
            self.fun()

    def start(self):
        self.thread =Thread(target=self.caller)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def join(self):
        self.thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    O1 = MyClass(1)
    O2 = MyClass(2)
    O1.join()
    O2.join()
```

Comment: Oh, so it needs to be joined to the main thread. Thanks alot for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `join` inside your `init` method, and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> [waits] until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates.

Remove the call to `join` from your `init` method, and `join` the threads after each has started inside your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot up your answer because my reputation is below 15, and i can only accept one answer. But i am very much thankful for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Carcigenicate's answer:

It practically *never* makes sense to `join()` a thread immediately after `start()`ing it.  The whole point of using threads is to allow different activities in your program to happen [*concurrently*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) with each other. E.g., In this example, `wash_the_clothes()` and `feed_the_pets()` both happen concurrently with each other:

```
t = Thread(target=wash_the_clothes)
t.start()
feed_the_pets(...)
t.join()
```

If you don't want to `feed_the_pets()` or do anything else concurrently with `wash_the_clothes()`, then there's no reason to create a thread. You can just *call* `wash_the_clothes()` at that point in your code.

Comment: I do understand the point you are trying to make, i am actually creating a service which pings multiple ports and I want the functions to run in-parallel, my approach wasn't working because it wasn't attached to the main thread right? I am very new to threading.